# Why we need convolution in image processing?

Tags: image-processing, convolution, correlation

To my understanding, there are two methods to do linear filtering. One is cross-correlation, and another is convolution. Convolution requires 'flipping' the kernel when you do the calculation.

I think that you can simply do cross-correlation without doing convolution. So I wonder why to choose convolution instead of correlation in image processing.

Comment: Filtering per se requires convolution. Cross correlation is mathematical the same as cross  correlation with a flipped (time or space) kernel. If the kernel is symmetric convolution and correlation are identical operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no particular reason in terms of the algorithm, anything you do with a convolution you can do with a correlation. What makes the convolution nicer is than correlation is that it is commutative and associative.

i.e. if you have multiple filters you could apply `conv(x, conv(h1, h2))` could be computed as `conv(conv(x, h1), h2)`, `conv(conv(x, h2), h1)`, `conv(x, conv(h2, h1))` (and others commuting x with the filters), so for analysis it is nice to use convolution, you can manipulate it like multiplications. In fact in the frequency domain the convolution reduces to a multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful what you mean when you say **cross-correlation**:  In statistical signal processing, that means:
$$
R_{xy} (\tau) = E\left [ x(t) y(t+\tau) \right ]
$$
where $E$ is the [expectation operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Random_variables_with_density). This has little to do with convolution.

Convolution, generally, doesn't have a statistical signal processing interpretation and so is less prone to misinterpretation.